# Speed of checking for failbit in ostream

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out why checking for a failbit of a stream is quicker when doing it explicitly than implicitly.

Let's say we have the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
  std::stream out(std::cout.rdbuf());
  out.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

  for (size_t idx = 0; idx != 1000000; ++idx)
  {
    if( out.good() )
      out << "Some test text." << '\n';       // Implementation 1

    out << "Different test text." << '\n';    // Implementation 2
  }
}
```

Given enough times to loop, the implementation using the if statement is significantly faster. (For a million loops, it's about 2s vs. 0.5s on my system)

In my mind it shouldn't make any difference. Wouldn't out.good() or out.fail() be the first check run when out is called to print something to an output? I'd love to check, but I can't find documentation on it.

It might be that the failbit is checked for every insertion operator, but I wouldn't know where to find out.

Where would I look to find out the difference in speed, or what's checked when out is called? This is for a course, so (also for my own fun) a pointer in the right direction instead of a full answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: For starters, Implementation 1 never calls `operator<<` and thus avoids all its overhead.

Comment: I'm not sure that the performance of the failing case is that important. Usually, I focus onto optimizing the "good" paths. If the code fails to do what it's supposed to I doesn't care so much about how fast it is while failing... ;-)

Comment: It's, of course, possible to abuse the failbit as a kind of flag to e.g. enable/disable log output. In this case, the speed of failing is in fact of interest. However, I still would consider it questionable to be of good style to make the "fail case" the "good case". Yet another flag wouldn't hurt for this intention, and contribute to the readability of the code IMHO.